# How do I account for new lines in text area when printing?

Tags: javascript, html

The user enters some input in a text area.
After they enter the text, they click "Generate" and the code will output the exact same text.

My issue is, when I input text with multiple lines, when I click "Generate", the function is not able to account for the new lines and simply prints what the user wrote on one big line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Minecraft Command Splitter by Jragon</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <h2>Please input your commands.</h2>
 <textarea id="userinput" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Write your compacted commands here and the output will split them for you!"></textarea>
 <button id="generate" onclick="thisButton(this)">Generate</button><br/>
 <br>
 <h5>Output</h5>
 <div id="output"></div>
 
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">  

function gen_output(ad_content){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ad_content;
}


function print(input) {
 if (input == undefined) {
  input = "";
 }

 gen_output(input);
}

function println(input) {
  if (input == undefined) {
   input = "";
  }

  print(input + "<br>");
 }

function thisButton(buttonElement){
  var buttonClickedId = buttonElement.id;
  var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  if( buttonClickedId === 'generate' ){
    println(input);
 }
}
</script>
```

So if I write:
"Hello 1"
"Hello 2"
"Hello 3"

It will print as "Hello 1 Hello 2 Hello 3" insetad of
"Hello 1"
"Hello 2"
"Hello 3"

Comment: What does this problem have to do with using `.getElementById()`? Anyway, this is happening because of the standard way whitespace characters in an HTML string are treated, i.e., spaces, tabs, newlines all get condensed down to a single space when displayed. Try `.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')` to convert the newline characters to break elements. Or output into a `<pre>` element.

Comment: My apologies. I meant printing, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I just placed ""ad_content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');"" into my gen_output function and unfortunately the result is the same. Am I doing it wrong?
EDIT: Yeah I'm an idiot, I was supposed to do this:
"  var ad_content = ad_content.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");  "

Comment: Use `white-space: pre-line` or equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#doIt').click(function () {
    var encodedStr = $('#inputText').val().replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
       return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
    });
    $('#output').html(encodedStr.replace(/&/gim, '&amp;'));
});
```

```css
code {
    display:block;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputText"></textarea>
<button id="doIt">do it</button>

<h3>result</h3>
<code id="output"></code>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E3EqX/13/

Try this fiddle It will encode the html entities in javascript.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I just ran it and when I input hello1,hello2,hello3 on separate lines, it still printed it on multiple lines.

Answer (score -1):

Please enter `<br>` onchange the value of text area. I mean insert compatible character.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    *<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Minecraft Command Splitter by Jragon</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">


    </head>
    <body>*


    <h2>Please input your commands.</h2>
    <textarea id="userinput" onChange="htmlFormat()" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Write your compacted commands here and the output will split them for you!"></textarea>
    <button id="generate" onclick="thisButton(this)">Generate</button><br/>
    <br>
    <h5>Output</h5>
    <div id="output"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">  
function htmlFormat(){
  var text = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  document.getElementById("userinput").value = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
}
function gen_output(ad_content){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ad_content;
}


function print(input) {
    if (input == undefined) {
        input = "";
    }

    gen_output(input);
}

function println(input) {
        if (input == undefined) {
            input = "";
        }

        print(input + "<br>");
    }

function thisButton(buttonElement){
  var buttonClickedId = buttonElement.id;
  var input = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  if( buttonClickedId === 'generate' ){
    println(input);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/9Xv1vbHkZKvw5bSafZ7c?p=preview

Comment: This solution is far inferior to simply using CSS to direct that the whitespace be honored.